# Finite difference method for 1D Poisson equation with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

I have solved the following 1D Poisson equation using finite difference method:

```
u'' = 6 x; u'(0) = 0; u(1) = 1;
```

where h = 1/3; i.e., I found u(0), u(1/3) and u(2/3)

I construct the linear system $A\,u = b$, where

```
A = {{-2, 2, 0}, {1, -2, 1}, {0, 1, -2}};
b = {0, 2/9, -5/9};
LinearSolve[A, b]
```

I got `{1/9, 1/9, 1/3}`.

I want to solve the equation with  different types of boundary conditions.
Please what happen if the boundary conditions change to

1. u(0) = 0, u'(1) = 3,
2. u'(0) = 0, u'(1) = 3

I need to construct A and b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### case 1. u(0) = 0, u'(1) = 3.

[image]

The first step is to solve for $u_{n+1}$. From equation (1)
$$
u_{n+1}=2h\alpha+u_{n-1}
$$
Substituting this into (2) gives the equation for the last point
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+u_{n+1}}{h^{2}}  & =f_{n}\nonumber\\
\frac{u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+\left(  2h\alpha+u_{n-1}\right)  }{h^{2}}  &
=f_{n}\nonumber\\
\frac{2u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+2h\alpha}{h^{2}}  & =f_{n}\nonumber\\
2u_{n-1}-2u_{n}  & =h^{2}f_{n}-2h\alpha\tag{3}
\end{align}
Therefore, the equations are: For the first node $u_{1}=\beta$, for the second
node at $i=2$ and using $\frac{u_{i-1}-2u_{i}+u_{i+1}}{h^{2}}=f_{i}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{1}-2u_{2}+u_{3}}{h^{2}}  & =f_{2}\\
u_{1}-2u_{2}+u_{3}  & =h^{2}f_{2}
\end{align*}
And for the third node
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{2}-2u_{3}+u_{4}}{h^{2}}  & =f_{3}\\
u_{2}-2u_{3}+u_{4}  & =h^{2}f_{3}
\end{align*}
And so on until node $i=n$ which is (3)
$$
2u_{n-1}-2u_{n}=h^{2}f_{n}-2h\alpha
$$
Putting these matrix form gives
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}\\
u_{2}\\
u_{3}\\
\vdots\\
u_{n-2}\\
u_{n-1}\\
u_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
& =
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta\\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{2}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{3}\right)  \\
\vdots\\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n-2}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n-1}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n}\right)  -2h\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\\
Au  & =b
\end{align*}

[image]

code

```
makeA[n_] := Module[{A, i, j},
      A = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, n}];
      Do[
          Do[

     A[[i, j]] = If[i == j, -2, If[i == j + 1 || i == j - 1, 1, 0]],
               {j, 1, n}
             ],
          {i, 1, n}
       ];

      A[[1, 1]] = 1;
      A[[1, 2]] = 0;
      A[[-1, -2]] = 2;
      A
      ];
makeB[n_, h_, force_, leftBC_, rightBC_] := Module[{b, i},
      b = Table[0, {i, n}];
      Do[

    b[[i]] = 
     If[i == 1, leftBC, 
      If[i < n, f[(i - 1)*h]*h^2, (h^2*f[(i - 1)*h] - 2 h rightBC) ]
            ]
        , {i, 1, n}
        ];
      b
      ];
f[x_] := 6*x;(*RHS of ode*)
Manipulate[
  Module[{h, A, b, sol, solN, p1, p2, x, leftBC, rightBC},
    h = 1/(nPoints - 1);
    leftBC = 0;
    rightBC = 3;
    A = makeA[nPoints];
    b = makeB[nPoints, h, f, leftBC, rightBC];
    sol = LinearSolve[A, b];
    solN = Table[{n*h, sol[[n + 1]]}, {n, 0, nPoints - 1}];

    p1 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]; (*exact solution*)

    p2 = ListLinePlot[solN, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> All];

    Grid[{
            {Row[{" h = ", NumberForm[N@h, {5, 4}]}]},
            {Row[{MatrixForm[A], MatrixForm[Array[u, nPoints]] , 
                        " = ", MatrixForm[N@b] }]},
            {Show[p1, p2,                      
                 PlotLabel -> "Red is numerical, Blue is exact solution",
                 GridLines -> Automatic,
                 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, ImageSize -> 400
                 ]
             }
          }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 2}
       ]
    ],
  {{nPoints, 3, "How many points?"}, 3, 8, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {nPoints}
  ]
```

### case 2 u'(0) = 0, u'(1) = 3

[image]

The first step is to solve for $u_{n+1}$. From equation (1)
$$
u_{n+1}=2h\alpha+u_{n-1}
$$
Substituting this into (2) gives the equation for the last point
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+u_{n+1}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{n}\nonumber\\
\frac{u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+\left(  2h\alpha+u_{n-1}\right)  }{h^{2}} &
=f_{n}\nonumber\\
\frac{2u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+2h\alpha}{h^{2}} &  =f_{n}\nonumber\\
2u_{n-1}-2u_{n} &  =h^{2}f_{n}-2h\alpha\tag{3}
\end{align}

Similary we solve for $u_{0}$. From equation (3)
$$
u_{0}=u_{2}-2h\beta
$$
Substituting this into (4) gives the equation for the first point
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{0}-2u_{1}+u_{2}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{0}\nonumber\\
\frac{\left(  u_{2}-2h\beta\right)  -2u_{1}+u_{2}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{0}\nonumber\\
\frac{2u_{2}-2h\beta-2u_{1}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{0}\nonumber\\
2u_{2}-2u_{1} &  =f_{0}h^{2}+2h\beta\tag{3}
\end{align}

Therefore, the equations are: For the first node
$$
2u_{2}-2u_{1}=f_{0}h^{2}+2h\beta
$$
For the second node at $i=2$ and using $\frac{u_{i-1}-2u_{i}+u_{i+1}}{h^{2}
}=f_{i}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{1}-2u_{2}+u_{3}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{2}\\
u_{1}-2u_{2}+u_{3} &  =h^{2}f_{2}
\end{align*}
And for the third node
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{2}-2u_{3}+u_{4}}{h^{2}} &  =f_{3}\\
u_{2}-2u_{3}+u_{4} &  =h^{2}f_{3}
\end{align*}
And so on until node $i=n$ which is (3)
$$
2u_{n-1}-2u_{n}=h^{2}f_{n}-2h\alpha
$$
Putting these matrix form gives
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1}\\
u_{2}\\
u_{3}\\
\vdots\\
u_{n-2}\\
u_{n-1}\\
u_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
&  =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{0}h^{2}+2h\beta\\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{2}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{3}\right)  \\
\vdots\\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n-2}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n-1}\right)  \\
h^{2}f\left(  x_{n}\right)  -2h\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\\
Au &  =b
\end{align*}

The analytical solution for $u^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  =6x$ with
$u^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  =0,u^{\prime}\left(  1\right)  =3$ is not unique.
It is $x^{3}+C$. The constant $C$ is arbitrary and an infinite number of
solutions exist. A solution exist which is up to an arbitrary additive
constant. To select a constant for the purpose of the numerical analysis, the
constant is found to give the analytical solution a zero mean which is done by
solving

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(  x^{3}+C\right)  dx  & =0\\
\left[  \frac{x^{4}}{4}+Cx\right]  _{0}^{1}  & =0\\
\frac{1}{4}+C  & =0\\
C  & =-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Hence the solution $u\left(  x\right)  =x^{3}-\frac{1}{4}$ is used.

[image]

code

```
makeA[n_] := Module[{A, i, j},
      A = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, n}];
      Do[
          Do[                   
             A[[i, j]] = If[i == j, -2, If[i == j + 1 || i == j - 1, 1, 0]],
               {j, 1, n}
             ],
          {i, 1, n}
       ];

      A[[1, 2]] = 2;
      A[[-1, -2]] = 2;
      A
      ];
makeB[n_, h_, force_, leftBC_, rightBC_] := Module[{b, i},
      b = Table[0, {i, n}];
      Do[              
         b[[i]] = If[i == 1, f[0]*h^2 + 2*h*leftBC, 
           If[i < n, f[(i - 1)*h]*h^2, (h^2*f[(i - 1)*h] - 2 h rightBC) ]
              ]
        , {i, 1, n}
        ];
      b
      ];
f[x_] := 6*x;(*RHS of ode*)
Manipulate[
  Module[{h, A, b, sol, solN, p1, p2, x, leftBC, rightBC, 
   normalizationConstant},
    h       = 1/(nPoints - 1);
    leftBC  = 0;
    rightBC = 3;
    A       = makeA[nPoints];
    b       = makeB[nPoints, h, f, leftBC, rightBC];
    sol     = LinearSolve[A, b];
    solN    = Table[{n*h, sol[[n + 1]]}, {n, 0, nPoints - 1}];
    normalizationConstant = -1/4;
    solN[[All, 2]] =        solN[[All, 2]] - Mean[solN[[All, 2]]]; (*To match normalization *)

    p1 = Plot[x^3 + normalizationConstant, {x, 0, 1}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.4, 1}}]; (*exact solution*)
    p2 = ListLinePlot[solN, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> All];
    Grid[{
            {Row[{" h = ", NumberForm[N@h, {5, 4}]}]},
            {Row[{MatrixForm[A], MatrixForm[Array[u, nPoints]] , 
               " = ", MatrixForm[N@b] }]},
            {Show[p1, p2, 
                PlotLabel -> "Red is numerical, Blue is exact solution",
                GridLines -> Automatic,
                GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, ImageSize -> 400
                ]
             }
          }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 2}
       ]
    ],
  {{nPoints, 3, "How many points?"}, 3, 20, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {nPoints}
  ]
```

**Update, answering comment**

Hard to answer this in comment as I have to show large code.

> solve u''=2, u'(0)=0,u'(1)=2, the exact now x^2+c, c=-1/3,.. the error
>   is big, why

The error is not big at all. as you add more nodes it goes down as expected. you must made mistake somewhere changing the above code for the new ode you are now asking about. You have to change `f` and change boundary conditions and change the `normalization constant`. Here is the Manipulate for the above ODE

```
makeA[n_] := Module[{A, i, j},
      A = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, n}];
      Do[
          Do[                   
            A[[i, j]] = If[i == j, -2, If[i == j + 1 || i == j - 1, 1, 0]],
               {j, 1, n}
             ],
          {i, 1, n}
       ];

      A[[1, 2]] = 2;
      A[[-1, -2]] = 2;
      A
      ];
makeB[n_, h_, force_, leftBC_, rightBC_] := Module[{b, i},
      b = Table[0, {i, n}];
      Do[                     b[[i]] = 
        If[i == 1, f[0]*h^2 + 2*h*leftBC, 
        If[i < n, f[(i - 1)*h]*h^2, (h^2*f[(i - 1)*h] - 2 h rightBC) ]
            ]
        , {i, 1, n}
        ];
      b
      ];
f[x_] := 2;(*RHS of ode*)
Manipulate[
  Module[{h, A, b, sol, solN, p1, p2, x, leftBC, rightBC, 
   normalizationConstant},
    h = 1/(nPoints - 1);
    leftBC = 0;
    rightBC = 2;
    A = makeA[nPoints];
    b = makeB[nPoints, h, f, leftBC, rightBC];
    sol = LinearSolve[A, b];
    solN = Table[{n*h, sol[[n + 1]]}, {n, 0, nPoints - 1}];
    normalizationConstant = -1/3;
    solN[[All, 2]] = solN[[All, 2]] - Mean[solN[[All, 2]]]; (*To match normalization *)

    p1 = Plot[x^2 + normalizationConstant, {x, 0, 1}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
       PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.4, 1}}]; (*exact solution*)
       p2 = ListLinePlot[solN, PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> All];
    Grid[{
            {Row[{" h = ", NumberForm[N@h, {5, 4}]}]},
            {Row[{MatrixForm[A], MatrixForm[Array[u, nPoints]] , 
                  " = ", MatrixForm[N@b] }]},
            {Show[p1, p2, 

      PlotLabel -> "Red is numerical, Blue is exact solution",
                 GridLines -> Automatic,
                 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, ImageSize -> 400
                 ]
             }
          }, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 2}
       ]
    ],
  {{nPoints, 3, "How many points?"}, 3, 20, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {nPoints}
  ]
```

If you run this, you'll see the error is small and gets smaller with larger nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr.Nasser, I highly appreciate your help. Just for other case which is Neumann B.C. I think it is not uniquely solvable due to the derivative, i.e. if u=x^3 solution then x^3+c also solution right?

Comment: @user62716 Yes, The analytical solution for case 2 is not unique. The constant $c$ is arbitrary and an inﬁnite number of solutions exist. A solution exist which is up to an arbitrary additive constant. To select a constant for the purpose of the numerical analysis, the constant is selected to give the analytical solution a zero mean. i.e. solve $\int_0^1 (x^3+c) \, dx=0$  for $c$. This gives $c=-\frac{1}{4}$ and use this $c$ to compare the numerical solution with the analytical solution now by fixing $c$. If it is still not clear I can add case 2 also later on.

Comment: Dear Dr. Nasser, many thanks for your help and top clarification, I will be happy to see Neumann case 2, but I am sorry I took too much time from you.

Comment: Many thanks  Dr.Nasser for your great help today I highly appreciate that. Just minor correction in your great well-written part in both case in third term in vector b, I thing it is h^2 f(x3) not h^2 f(x2). Best wishes and regards, I will move to 2D Laplace or maybe 3D  with different types of boundary conditions.

Comment: @user62716 thanks. There were latex cut/paste error. Corrected.

Comment: Many thanks Dr.Nasser.

Comment: Dear Nasser, I have try to solve u''=2, u'(0)=0,u'(1)=2, the exact now x^2+c, c=-1/3 for h=1/3, so it is second order, i.e we need to find u(0),u(1/3),u(2/3) and u(1) the error is big, why?

Comment: This step solN[[All, 2]] = solN[[All, 2]] - Mean[solN[[All, 2]]]; for what please?I know you calculate numerical solution but -Mean?

Comment: `solve u''=2, u'(0)=0,u'(1)=2, the exact now x^2+c, c=-1/3,.. the error is big, why` the error is not big at all. as you add more nodes it goes down as expected. you must made mistake somewhere changing the code for the new ode. I'll post the new code for this. You have to change `f` and change boundary conditions and change the normalization constant.

Comment: `This step solN[[All, 2]] = solN[[All, 2]] - Mean[solN[[All, 2]]]; for what`  Because this is special case. There is no unique solution. So we adjusted the analytical solution by finding constant which makes the mean zero. i.e. the analytical solution shown has zero mean. To do the same for the numerical solution (so we are comparing apples to apples) we need to subtract the mean there also.

Comment: Dear Nasser, many thanks I also modify your code as you did, by hand I don't used the Mean step so I got the error, please do you have any link or website about normalization issue?

Comment: I mean for the new ode u''=2, I got {-1, -(8/9), -(5/9), 0} by hand without using the Mean step that why I asked about this step

Comment: @user62716 that is correct, For 4 nodes, you'll get `{-1, -(8/9), -(5/9), 0}` but you have to make the numerical solution have zero mean! we talked about why this is so. In order to compare it with analytical solution. How do you make list of number have zero mean? Say you have `{4,5,6}` and want to change them so the mean is zero? You subtract the mean, which is 5, this  gives `{-1,0,1}` and now the numerical solution has zero mean, like the analytical solution. Remember, we forced the analytical solution to have zero mean, in order find the unknown constant....

Comment: ...since there is no unique solution. You only need to do this when ODE has no unique solution like your examples. I do not know of a web site that describes these things. May be googling will find one.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr.Nasser for your really very clear details and very nice explanation I am more than happy to always learn from you. Take care...